# jqGrid Additional POST datas when deleting

Tags: jqgrid, rowdeleting

I want to delete a row in the grid, but the grid always post's only the id and oper, I also want to post additional data.

My jqgrid is something like :

`jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({

    url:'autoJSON.php',
 datatype: "xml",
    colNames:['RowID','Asigurator','Cilindree','Persoana', 'Perioada', 'Pret'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'rowID',index:'rowID', width:60, editable:true},
     {name:'idAsigurator',index:'idAsigurator', width:100, editable:true,editoptions:{size:20}},

     {name:'cilindree',index:'cilindree', width:90, editable:true,editoptions:{size:20}},
     {name:'persoana',index:'persoana', width:300,editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Persoana juridica:Persoana juridica;Pensionar:Pensionar;Persoana fizica:Persoana fizica"}},
     {name:'perioada',index:'perioada', width:120, align:"right",edittype:"select",editable:true,editoptions:{value:"12 luni:12 luni;6 luni:6 luni"}},
     {name:'pret',index:'pret', width:80, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:20}} 
    ],
 width:900, 
 height:600,
    pager: '#pagered', 
    sortname: 'rowID',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Autoturisme",
    editurl:"autoPOST.php",
});
jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pagered",{edit:true,add:true,del:true});`

What should I do to access in autoPOST.php rowID also as a post variable.

Thanks

---

When trying to delete the only post variables I see are oper='del' and id that returns the id of the selected row i want to delete

Comment: this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833254/jqgrid-delete-row-how-to-send-additional-post-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` sent with the POST when you delete data should correspond to the `rowId` of each row. To make this happen, you need to add the following option to `.jqGrid({` when the grid is intialized:

```
 xmlReader: {
            root:"xml", // Varies depending upon the structure of your XML
            row:"item", // Varies depending upon the structure of your XML
            repeatitems:false,
            id:"rowID"
},
```

Values of `root` and `row` will vary depending upon how your XML is named. The previous example will parse the following XML:

```
<xml>
 <item>
  <rowId>1</rowId>
  ...
 </item>
</xml>
```

Does that help?

Comment: I'm using FIREBUG and the rowID isnt sent as a POST variable when deleting...

When editing the rowID is send as a POST variable  ...

That's my problem

Comment: The XML I use is created on the fly based on the example of editing.php file provided in the examples of jqgrid library.

Comment: Did you try using the method above, or is it not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting your question
"I also want to post additional data.",
I assume you want to post another variable beside the rowId and 'del'.
You can use postext plugin. This plugin provides additional API : setPostData(), setPostDataItem(), etc.