# Parameter Delete in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, jqgrid-inlinenav

i want implement Delete for jqGrid, i have (example) 2 table Request and Item

Request Fields are `RequestId`,`WayBillNo`,`Customer`
Item Fields are `RequestId`,`ItemNO`,`Quantity`
Request table `RequestId` is pk and in item table pk are `RequestId`,`ItemNO` i write this code for item table

```js
var requestIdItem=0, itemIdItem=0;
var gridItem = $('#listItem');
gridItem.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceItems', Action: 'Fill', requestId: rowid },
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 200,
    colNames: ['RequestId','ItemNo',Quantity],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true,hidden:true },
        { name: 'ITEM_NO', width: 200, sortable: true }
        { name: 'Quntity', width: 100, sortable: true  }
    ],
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 40, 60],
    pager: '#pagerItem',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'ASC',
    rownumbers: true,
    //onSelectRow: function (id, state) {
    //    requestIdItem = gridItem.jqGrid('getCell', id, 'REQUEST_ID_ID');
    //    alert(requestIdItem);
    //    itemIdItem = gridItem.jqGrid('getCell', id, 'ITEM_NO');
    //    alert(itemIdItem);
    //}
    //,
    beforeSelectRow: function (itemid, ex) {
        requestIdItem = gridItem.jqGrid('getCell', itemid, 'REQUEST_ID_ID');
        itemIdItem = gridItem.jqGrid('getCell', itemid, 'ITEM_NO');

        return true;
    }

});
gridItem.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerItem', { add: false, edit: false, del: true }, {}, {}, {
    //alert(requestIdItem);
    url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=ClearanceItems&Action=Delete&REQUEST_ID=" +
         requestIdItem + "&ITEM_NO=" + itemIdItem
}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });
```

i write this code for item table , now i want write code for delete item in Item table i write this code for send parameters value

```
url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=ClearanceItems&Action=Delete&REQUEST_ID=" +
     requestIdItem + "&ITEM_NO=" + itemIdItem
```

but always send 0 value to server, please help me. thanks all

EDIT01: i change Delete Option For this:
I see in this page `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833254/jqgrid-delete-row-how-to-send-additional-post-data` user @Oleg write this code

```js
gridItem.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerItem', { add: false, edit: false, del: true }, {}, {}, {
    serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
        alert(postdata.id);
        return ""; // the body MUST be empty in DELETE HTTP requests
    },
    onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, postdata) {
        //  alert(postdata.id);
        var rowdata = $("#listItem").getRowData(postdata.id);
        alert(rowdata.REQUEST_ID_ID);
        rp_ge.url = 'JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=ClearanceItems&Action=Delete&' +
                    $.param({ rr: rowdata.REQUEST_ID_ID });

        // 'subgrid.process.php/' + encodeURIComponent(postdata.id) +
        //    '?' + jQuery.param({ user_id: rowdata.user_id });
    }
    //alert(requestIdItem);
    // url: "JQGridHandler.ashx?ActionPage=ClearanceItems&Action=Delete&REQUEST_ID=" +
    //      requestIdItem + "&ITEM_NO=" + itemIdItem
}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 })
```

when send Data to server send `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it seems to me that you have typing error in your code. You should replace `REQUEST_ID_ID` to `REQUEST_ID` everywhere in your code.

If you need to send some additional information to the server you can use

```js
onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, postdata) {
    var requestId = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", postdata.id, "REQUEST_ID");
    // alert("REQUEST_ID=" + requestId);
    return { rr: requestId });
}
```

In the case `rr` will be posted as additional parameter of the Delete request together with `id` parameter.

If you need really send the information as the part of URL instead of the part of body of the POST request you can do the following

```js
onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, postdata) {
    var requestId = $(this).jqGrid("getCell", postdata.id, "REQUEST_ID");
    // alert("REQUEST_ID=" + requestId);
    rp_ge.url = "JQGridHandler.ashx?" +
        $.param({
            ActionPage: "ClearanceItems",
            Action: "Delete",
            rr: requestId
        });
}
```